# Use the same JS file on more than one page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress theme and I'm trying to make an effect that when the user clicks on the button, a search bar opens.

I place the button on the header.php and the script on footer.php

But it's working just on the front-page of my theme, on the other pages I get some erros:

*"js.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'open_search_btn' has already been declared"*

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
at HTMLImageElement.*

Footer:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php $template_url = get_template_directory_uri();?>



    <footer>
    
    <a href="/"><img src="<?php echo $template_url?>/assets/images/image.png" alt=" " class="img-fluid"></a>
    
    </footer>
    
    
    
    <script src="<?php echo $template_url?>/assets/js/js.js"></script>
    


</body>

</html>
```

JS File:

```
const open_search_btn = document.querySelector(".search-button");
const form_wrapper = document.querySelector(".form-wrapper");
const close_search_btn = document.querySelector(".close-search-btn");

open_search_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    form_wrapper.classList.toggle("form-wrapper-active"); 

    close_search_btn.classList.toggle("close-search-btn-active");

})


close_search_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    form_wrapper.classList.remove("form-wrapper-active");
    close_search_btn.classList.remove("close-search-btn-active");

})
```

Comment: Is it possible that you call the same JS file more than once on the same page?

Comment: No, not in the same page. The JS is called on the footer, so I call it on every page that has a footer (all pages)

Comment: Those JS errors indicate that you are declaring "open_search_btn" in some other javascript on the page, and that the search button does not exist yet when you are declaring it. Since it is not happening on the front page there is something different in the front page template file than the regular page template file. Look in the files and check for any extra JS files being loaded in page, or look for "is_page" or "is_home" in the functions.php file to see if extra scripts are being registered there.